# Bash Shell Scripting - How to iterate through directories, and copy and rename files?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have a directory setup as follows:

```
/hosted/partner1/logo.png
/hosted/partner2/logo.png
/hosted/partner3/logo.png
/hosted/partner4/logo.png
/hosted/partner5/logo.png
..etc.
```

I want to write a script that can COPY those files to a different location, with a different file name, like this:

```
/partners/partner1.png
/partners/partner2.png
/partners/partner3.png
..etc.
```

Any ideas?  I'm not so great with shell scripting and there are a lot of files that I need to migrate to a single directory...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find /hosted -maxdepth 1 -name "partner*" -type d | while read -r dir
do
    cp "${dir}/logo.png" "/partners/$(basename ${dir}).png"
done
```

Or

```
find /hosted -maxdepth 1 -name "partner*" -type d | while read -r dir
do
    cp "${dir}/logo.png" "/partners/${dir##*/}.png"
done
```